# How do I setup a c++/cli program to handle arguments and piped in text like in find command

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

How do I properly setup my arguments if my program's name is Test.exe using the code below?  I'm thinking that I need to add arguments to check for | command, but I don't need to do this if I use the redirect command ">".  So I think I need to use a Stream reader in c++ but am not 100% sure how to implement it for any number of lines piped in:

```
 using namespace System;   
 using namespace System::IO;
    int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
    {
      // this doesn't work with piped in text
      Console::WriteLine(":::{0}:::", args[0]);
    }
```

At the command prompt I type "test a" and hit enter.

```
:::a:::
```

At the command prompt I type "echo hello world | test "

```
:::hello world:::
```

An example of how this is implemented at the Windows Command prompt is with the find command.  I'm trying to implement this in my c++/cli program using Visual Studio 2012.   Example: "help find":

```
If a path is not specified, FIND searches the text typed at the prompt
or piped from another command.
```

Comment: how do I delete a question? ;)

Comment: not a real question b/c args use system process to call next piped process.   For some reason I was thinking the console magically handled piped arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program doesn't see the pipe. The pipe is something that the shell uses to redirect `stdout` from the first program to the `stdin` of the second program. This means in `Test.exe`, you'll get the input by using `Console::Readline`:

```
Console::WriteLine(":::{0}:::", Console::ReadLine());
```

Comment: Thanks.  I believe you are 100% correct if the piped text is only 1 line.

Comment: Updated the question for any number of lines piped in.

Comment: @RetroCoder how you handle multiple lines is up to how you will use it. If you're only expecting a few lines you can loop over `Console::ReadLine()` and buffer up the text, and process when it's all done. If there's potentially lots of text, you may want to expand that loop so you are reading and processing one line at a time.

Comment: thanks already there... I'm not going to create a new buffer but push the stream into a reader.